# Is it possible to automatically restart killed erlang applications?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I have an application, my_app. It has some other applications it depends on.

my_app.app:

```
{application, my_app,
 [ {description, "My App"},
   {vsn, "0.0.1"},
   {registered, []},
   {applications, [some_dep1,
                   some_dep2]},
   {mod, {my_app_app, []}},
   {env, []}
 ]}.
```

If either `some_dep1` or `some_dep2` fail to start, `my_app` will also fail to start. So far, so good.

However, if something goes wrong during running the system and `some_dep1` blows up (taking out supervisors all the way up the tree), erlang will eventually kill the `some_dep1` application; however my_app isn't killed, nor it is notified (that I can find)

Is there a way to handle this? Ideally, I'd like it to restart (just like supervisors handle restarts, with thresholds etc), or alternatively kill any applications that depend on it.

My current thinking is polling for application state, but that seems like a giant hack.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If an application is started as a "permanent" application, the entire Erlang node will go down if the application crashes.  This is the default when generating a release, but if you're using `application:start` or `application:ensure_all_started`, the default type is `temporary`, which means that the application just dies silently, as you've observed.  Try something like:

```
application:start(some_dep1, permanent)
```

or

```
application:ensure_all_started(my_app, permanent)
```

There is no supervisor-like thing for applications: if an application crashes, it means that its top-level supervisor has crashed, suggesting that the application doesn't know what more it can do to rectify the problem.  (If restarting the application would have fixed the problem, it could equally well have been fixed by increasing the restart limit in the top-level supervisor.) The next level of "supervision" is [heart](http://erlang.org/doc/man/heart.html), which restarts an Erlang node if it crashes.

Comment: Ok, that makes me slightly more comfortable - we have AWS watching some status emitters in our erlang node; so if the whole node blows up, AWS will replace it. Thanks!